# Whitelist extensions for Google Chromium

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to deploy a standalone build of Chromium to run a web app on customer machines which can't have full Chrome installed on them. With a recent build of Chromium 20, when running in `--single-process` mode Chromium is being crashed by the Skype extension, so I'd like to disable that extension. I'm also bundling my own pre-installed extension, so I don't want to fully disable all extensions.

Ideally I would be able to blacklist all extensions just for my install of Chromium, and whitelist just my extension. I'd like to do this in a way which doesn't affect other installs of Chrome on the machine. I'm installing my extension through `master_preferences`, can I set a whitelist there too?

Answer (score 2):

Set a name in your extension's manifest. Then in the extension itself set the same name in a variable (eg: `window.___NAME`). Then use this code:

```
function DisableOtherExtensions(){
    chrome.management.getAll(function(ext){
        if(ext.length===1) return;

        for(var i=0; i<ext.length; i++){
            if(ext[i].name===____NAME) continue;
            chrome.management.setEnabled(ext[i].id,false);
        }
    });
}

chrome.management.onEnabled.addListener(DisableOtherExtensions);
chrome.management.onInstalled.addListener(DisableOtherExtensions);
```

And it won't let Chrome enable any other extensions but yours. Also deployment instructions are here: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/external_extensions.html.